# Insert non literal values with codeigniters active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to insert values like NOW() or users.username with active record. Codeigniter always wraps the values in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is - by using the set() method with the third parameter set to FALSE.

```
$this->db->set('date', 'NOW()', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('mytable');
```